# Swift UITableview Reload Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm stuck with the following, any inputs would be highly appreciated.

My app has a UITableViewController with custom cells. Let's name its UITableView as TABLE VIEW-1. I am using XIB as its custom cell. Inside that xib, there is another UITableView, (TABLE VIEW-2), with another XIB as its custom cell.

My question is, How can I reload cells of (TABLE VIEW-2) from (TABLE VIEW-1) once I get data from an API in (TABLE VIEW-1). I want to use delegate and protocols to do this.

OR, What would be the correct way of performing this and how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a reference of TableView1 in the TableView2 ViewController. You can do this by

-- Open the Assistant Editor

-- Right-click and drag from your UI element (i.e. label) to the code file

-- Xcode auto inserts code for you to create the name and connection

2. Then call `tableView2.reloadData()`, where tableView2 is the name of the outlet you just created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. These two tables have different classes. Xcode can't create a reference of TableView1 in the TableView2 ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a reference of the TABLE VIEW-2 in the TABLE VIEW-1 custom cell (TABLE VIEW-1 CELL)
2. Create a method inside TABLE VIEW-1 CELL to reload its data alone with the TABLE VIEW-2  (Optional but useful to organize your code)
3. Inside the tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell of the TABLE VIEW-1 call reload function

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mainTable: UITableView!
    
    let sampleData = [
        (section: "News", SubSections: [
            "Breaking news",
            "Current Affairs",
            "Local"
        ]) ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.mainTable.estimatedRowHeight = 200
        self.mainTable.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        
        let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: MainCell.self), bundle: Bundle.main)
        self.mainTable.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: MainCell.self))
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.sampleData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell: MainCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MainCell.self), for: indexPath) as! MainCell
        
        let sectionData = self.sampleData[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.setUpData(title: sectionData.section, data: sectionData.SubSections)
        
        return cell
    }
}


class MainCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var sectionTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var internalTable: UITableView!
    
    var tableData:[String]?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        self.internalTable.estimatedRowHeight = 200
        self.internalTable.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        
        let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: InsideCell.self), bundle: Bundle.main)
        self.internalTable.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: InsideCell.self))
    }

    func setUpData(title: String, data:[String]) {
        self.sectionTitle.text = title
        self.tableData = data
        self.internalTable.reloadData()
    }
    
}

extension MainCell: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.tableData?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell: InsideCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: InsideCell.self), for: indexPath) as! InsideCell
        
        if let subSectionData = self.tableData?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.subSectionTitle.text = subSectionData
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}

class InsideCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var subSectionTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Niroshan for your reply. I will try and come back.

Comment: Will this reload the entire table or just one cell?